# Can I use two Amazon MWS accounts from the same server?

Tags: amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral

Recently I used two MWS accounts from same server. And Amazon sent us an email that you are operating on two accounts.

Do they track IP's of API calls?

How can I use both accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using multiple developer credentials?  In my case, as a developer, I have a set of developer credentials that I use for all my clients.  I use the token and seller id that they provide me with.  I service multiple clients on a web page using a single set of dev credentials, only swapping in/out the client token and ID.

Check out this [FAQ](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/faq.html) for further info.

Comment: Thanks @ScottG. I am using multiple keys of different seller account. What is this developer credential. Is it something different from keys? And how to create and use developer credential. As all MWS API request for key and secret keys..

Comment: Read through those FAQ's.  It sounds like you're using multiple clients credentials (which yes are keys) together in the same application.  The proper way is for you to register as a developer, get you own set of credentials (keys), and then have each of your clients give you access by providing you their token.  That way, a client can revoke your access any time.  Each time you develop an application for a new client, you give them your developer ID, they generate a token and give that to you.  You simply plug in their token on all of your MWS calls, but you're using YOUR OWN dev. credential.

Comment: sorry to update in old thread. I have previously developed app using Direct keys not developer Id. But I want to do it now using developer Id for multiple sellers. Do I need to change my current IP? And Also as Mac Id can be tracked too, Do I need to change my computer too?

Comment: I think you'll be ok now because you're using a single set of credentials (your own developer id) for all of your sellers.  You're not sending them tokens from multiple accounts, which would be a red flag to Amazon.  Let me know!