# How to develop applications for multiple amazon Sellers using MWS services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral

I have a seller account in USA and I want to develop application for multiple sellers. But I fear if I access secret key and access key of multiple seller from same IP they will block seller accounts.

Note from docs:

> Important: Your Secret Key is a secret that only you and Amazon should know. It is important to keep it confidential to protect your account. Never include your Secret Key in your requests to Amazon MWS and never e-mail it to anyone. Never share it with anyone, even if they claim to be from Amazon. No one from Amazon will ever ask you for your Secret Key.

So, How should I proceed to develop multiple different sellers software?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use two Amazon MWS accounts from the same server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50378747/can-i-use-two-amazon-mws-accounts-from-the-same-server)

Comment: You asked this question last year.  The answer is to get a token from each seller.  Use that token along with your own set of keys and make the MWS calls.  You should never use keys given to you by another seller.  Use your own.

Comment: @ScottG What do you mean by your own set of keys? Is it Developer Id? And keys which comes with developer Id? And for other seller what key I need to change?

Comment: when you register as a developer, you should get an access key, secret access key, and a developer Id.  You give your developerId to a seller you want to write software for.  They authorize you in seller central and generate a token (MWSAuthToken).  They give the token to you.  You send that token on every request along with your access key (AWSAccessKeyId).  The have new pages since I started this a few years ago, but I think it's the same process.   https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/faq.html  http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_RequiredRequestParameters.html